# How to share an object between threads?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, list, shared-memory

I have a case where an object from one class is passed (as part of the initialization) to another class.

One of the classes, generally speaking, will update the object while the other one will output it (without modifications of the object). This will happen in separate threads.

```
import threading
import time
import random

class Consumer:

    def __init__(self):
        self.data = []

    def print(self):
        while True:
            print(self.data)
            time.sleep(1)

class Producer:

    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    def update(self):
        while True:
            self.data.append(random.random())


consumer = Consumer()
producer = Producer(consumer.data)
threading.Thread(target=consumer.print).run()
threading.Thread(target=producer.update).run()
```

I thought that `data` and `self.data` (in both classes) would ultimately point to the same data but this is not the case: the output is  a set of `[]` which shows that the modifications in `Producer` are not reflected in `Consumer`.

I will probably end up redesigning the code to avoid such tricks but I would really like to understand where the copy of `data` occured (which would explain why everything does not point to the same memory)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all - the reference to data is them same, you are initializing them correctly. You can check this by running `print(consumer.data is producer.data)` (this is pythons reference equality).

`run()` does not spawn a separate thread. It runs the thread function in the context of the current thread, so you are stuck in the `consumer.print` print loop, and `producer.update` is never actually called

You should call `.start()` instead:

```py
import threading
import time
import random

class Consumer:

    def __init__(self):
        self.data = []

    def print(self):
        while True:
            print(self.data)
            time.sleep(1)

class Producer:

    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    def update(self):
        while True:
            self.data.append(random.random())
            time.sleep(1)


consumer = Consumer()
producer = Producer(consumer.data)
threading.Thread(target=consumer.print).start()
threading.Thread(target=producer.update).start()
```

Comment: Ahhh, thank you. I do not know why I ended up with using `.run()` instead of `.start()`. It works great now.